# Removing the last loop comma as needed for schema script

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, schema, advanced-custom-fields

I just want to remove the comma on the last loop as the script does not work if there is still comma on the last part.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$faqs = get_field('questions_&_answers');
if( $faqs ) :
?>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context":"https://schema.org",
    "@type":"FAQPage",
    "mainEntity":[
<?php
    if( have_rows('questions_&_answers') ):
        $comma = ',';
        $i = 1;
        while ( have_rows('questions_&_answers') ) : the_row();
?>  
    {"@type":"Question","name":"<?=get_sub_field('question', false, false)?>","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"<?=get_sub_field('answer', false, false)?>"}}<?=($i < $faqs) ? $comma : '';?>
<?php
        $i++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>  
    ]
}
<?php
endif;
?>
</script>
```

and this is the result

```
{
    "@context":"https://schema.org",
    "@type":"FAQPage",
    "mainEntity":[

    {"@type":"Question","name":"My Question 1","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"My Answer 1"}},   
    {"@type":"Question","name":"My Question 2","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"My Answer 2"}},   
    ]
}
```

See the last part of the loop "My Question 2" still has a comma on the end, need to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to count the number of items in a repeater, you can do it like below:

```
<?php
$faqs = get_field('questions_&_answers');
if( $faqs ) :
    $rowCount = count( $faqs ); //Store the number of items in variable.
```

Then where you are displaying the comma, you need to check for above variable.

```
{"@type":"Question","name":"<?=get_sub_field('question', false, false)?>","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"<?=get_sub_field('answer', false, false)?>"}}
<?=($i < $faqs) ? $comma : '';?>
```

This should become like below. See how `$faqs` is replaced by `$rowCount`.

```
{"@type":"Question","name":"<?=get_sub_field('question', false, false)?>","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"<?=get_sub_field('answer', false, false)?>"}}
<?=($i < $rowCount) ? $comma : '';?> <!-- See the variable has been changed -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to work around this with your existing code is to output `$comma` at the beginning of each output string, but only set the `$comma` variable to `,` *after* you have output the first string:

```
<?php
    if( have_rows('questions_&_answers') ):
        $i = 1;
        $comma = '';
        while ( have_rows('questions_&_answers') ) : 
            the_row();
            echo $comma;
?>  
    {"@type":"Question","name":"<?=get_sub_field('question', false, false)?>","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"<?=get_sub_field('answer', false, false)?>"}}
<?php
        $comma = ',';
        $i++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
 function str_last_replace($search, $replace, $subject) {
        $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);

        if($pos !== false)
        {
            $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
        }

        return $subject;
     }
```